# How to check inserted and deleted items in UICollectionView, seeing unexpected deleted item

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am struggling to integrate `UICollectionView` and `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` in this particular case.

In my view controller, I fetch a Parent entity, but display its multiple Child entities in the collection view. When creating a new Parent entity in this view controller (with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`) and automatically creating a Child entity and adding it to the parent entity with `addChildObject`, I can add more Child entities by pressing a button, and save the object successfully. Unfortunately, for some reason the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are not called, specifically, `controllerDidChangeContent` is never called and the collection view doesn't get updated.

When I fetch an already existing Parent entity, and then try to change it by adding new Child objects, the app crashes with the following exception:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:], 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3505.17/UICollectionView.m:4211
```

And gives out this error in the end:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught 
from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to  
controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of items 
in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section 
after the update (5) must be equal to the number of items contained in 
that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of items 
inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus 
or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved 
in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

What puzzles me the most, is that it shows that there is a deleted item in `(1 inserted, 1 deleted)`, when, in fact, I am only adding an item (initializing a Child entity with `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` and adding it with `[parent addChildObject:child]`.

In all these cases, I am not saving the context. I expect adding objects to the parent entity to trigger `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods.

FetchResultsController setup code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self emojiFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Initializing parent object in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error];

id fetchedObject = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] firstObject];

if (fetchedObject != nil) {
    self.parent = (Parent *)fetchedObject;
    self.navigationItem.title = self.parent.name;
} else {
    self.navigationItem.title = @"New parent";
    self.parent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    Child *child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [self.parent addFramesObject:frame];
}
```

Adding new child objects:

```
Child *child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[self.parent addChildrenObject:child];

[self.collectionView reloadData]; // if this isn't done, the crash happens
// but this can't animate changes
```

Core Data Model:

[image: core data model]

Is there a way I can see those objects? I've tried logging `didChangeObject`, and I only see one insert. I am not deleting anything. If anyone has any other ideas, I'd be glad to hear them.

**EDIT**:

If I call `[self.collectionView reloadData]` after adding the objects, everything seems to work correctly without crashing. But, it would be nice for the changes to be animated, which cannot be done with `reloadData`, and I sense there is something fundamentally wrong with what I'm doing and I would like to fix it.

Comment: Show a picture of the model, the FRC setup code and the code adding the new objects

Comment: @Wain: please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution: Fetch the `Child` entity in your fetched results controller, filter by `parent`.

For inserts, use the plain vanilla implementation of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. This will provide a nice animation or let you add your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain why it is the best solution? According to my understanding, doesn't the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate listen to changes in the managed object context, and it isn't relevant in what order the entities are fetched as long as they are added to the context?

Comment: Why "best"? Because I cannot think of a better or simpler way. ;-) - The order of fetched objects is indeed random, but your FRC fetch request can have a *sort descriptor* which will take care of the display order. -- So just in case there is some confusion: the fetch I am referring to is done by the **fetched results controller**.